# Wait for AJAX response before moving on with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script which runs 2 AJAX calls, the first checks that a record exists within a database. If it does this should not move on and the script should stop. The second submits a job.

My problem is that the job is being submitted before the first AJAX call has returned. My code looks something like this:

```
if (recordid) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        context: document.body,
        url: URLGOESHERE,
        data: {
            recordID: recordid
        },
        success: function( data ){
            if (data.Response == "Success") {
                var noresults = data.Results;
                if (noresults > 0){
                    alert('this record id already exists!');
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                alert('an error occured');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    alert('enter a record id');
    return false;
}   

// second ajax call goes here, which gets called regardless of the output of the ajax call above
```

Comment: This is because the request is asynchronous. Put the second AJAX call *inside* the `success` handler of the first one. Also note that your use of `return` in the `success` handler is redundant.

Comment: Add parameter `async: false` to your `$.ajax`, or, even better, put the second request inside the `success` callback.

Comment: @eisbehr NO, never ever do that. `async: false` is *incredibly* bad practice. It blocks the UI thread form updating while the request is in progress which makes it look like the browser has crashed. This is the reason most browsers now throw console warnings about its use.

Comment: There is an option, he can use. I haven't decide if it is good or bad. It's his choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the call to the second ajax method at the bottom of your code (where the comments currently are), put it in the "success" function of your first call. This method will only execute once the first call has finished. This is the only way to ensure that the second call does not happen too early. Ajax calls run asynchronously, so the normal flow of the browser is not interrupted. This is deliberate so that long-running calls don't lock up the browser for the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (recordid) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        context: document.body,
        url: URLGOESHERE,
        data: {
            recordID: recordid
        },
        success: function(data) {

            //check here if you want to call submitJob or not
            //and call submitJob()
        }

    });

} else {
    alert('enter a record id');
    return false;
}

//call this ajax once you varified your condition from success callback of first one
function submitJob() {

    //second ajax call goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: make async propety false

```
if (recordid) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        context: document.body,
        url: URLGOESHERE,
        data: {
            recordID: recordid
        },
        async : false, //added this
        success: function( data ){
            if (data.Response == "Success") {
                var noresults = data.Results;
                if (noresults > 0){
                    alert('this record id already exists!');
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                alert('an error occured');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
} else {
    alert('enter a record id');
    return false;
}
```

OR 
perform second ajax call in success function of first ajax call i.e. see comment

```
if (recordid) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            context: document.body,
            url: URLGOESHERE,
            data: {
                recordID: recordid
            },
            success: function( data ){
                if (data.Response == "Success") {
                    var noresults = data.Results;
                    if (noresults > 0){
                        alert('this record id already exists!');
                        return false;
                    }
                    //perform 2nd ajax call here
                } else {
                    alert('an error occured');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('enter a record id');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Never use `async: false`, it is incredibly bad practice. It blocks the UI thread form updating while the request is in progress which makes it look like the browser has crashed. This is the reason most browsers now throw console warnings about its use.

Comment: so @Dr.Avalanche can perofom 2nd ajax call in success function of 1st ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `jquery promise` function for that which will wait for the first ajax request to complete then make another ajax request.

**[JQUERY PROMISE](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)**

**OR**

Put the second `ajax` request in the `success function` of first one, and make it happen when you want it to fire

```
 if (recordid) {
    var request = $.ajax({
    context: document.body,
    url: URLGOESHERE,
    data: {
        recordID: recordid
    },
    success: function(data) {

        //check here if you want to call submitJob or not
        if (noresults > 0){ return false }
        else { Job(); };

    }

   });

  } else {
     alert('enter a record id');
     return false;
   }

      function Job() {
             //another ajax call.
       }
```

Hope it helps :)